# How can I get error details for a SQL Insert done in Go?

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to insert some data into a Database with Go. Due to the nature of the data (large export from another tool), I hit sometimes some of my models constraints.

With the following Go code

```
_, err := db.Exec(query, params...)
if err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
}
```

I simply get an output like that

```
2023/03/10 09:40:26 pq: insert or update on table "table" violates foreign key constraint "table_constraint"
exit status 1
```

When I do the same Insert from pgAdmin, I get the same error but also some **DETAIL** information.

```
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(abc) is not present in table "table_2".
```

Is there a way to get this **DETAIL** information in Go as well? I checked the Documentation and couldn't find anything, but maybe there is a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the db driver that you're using will have a custom error type. You can assert the `err` value to this error type and then, depending on the driver's implementation, you should be able to glean more details about the issue. For example, when using `github.com/lib/pq`, you can assert to [`*pq.Error`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#Error) and read its [`Detail`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#Error.Detail) field:

```golang
_, err := db.Exec(query, params...)
if err != nil {
    if e, ok := err.(*pq.Error); ok {
        log.Print(e.Detail)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for! Wasn't aware that you can type assert errors, so this will help me with other packages in the future as well! Thanks :)